# Lindelöf image of γ-set

Tags: general-topology, proof-explanation

I am reading a paper. The link is as follows:
https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0166864109005124.

I am trying to understand the proof of (4) →(1)' of Theorem 54. To proceed, I start with a [$\omega$-cover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_principle)  $~\cal U$ of $Y$. As $Y$ is [Tychonoff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tychonoff_space) there is a refinement $\cal V$ of $\cal U$ consists of co-zero sets which covers $Y$. There is a countable subcollection of $\cal V$, viz. $\cal W$ covers $Y$. $\{f^{-1}(W):W\in \cal W\}$ is a cover of $X$ by co-zero sets. But this is not necessarily a $\omega$-cover.

> Then how to use (4) to reach to (1)'?

Comment: To show property $(\gamma)$ for $Y$ you start off wrong: start with a *sequence* of $\omega$-covers.

Comment: It is known that $\binom{\Omega}{\Gamma}=S_{1}(\Omega,\Gamma)=S_{fin}(\Omega,\Gamma)$. However if I start with a sequence of ω-covers $(\cu_n:n\in \bn)$ of Y. Now as Y is Tychonoff  there is a refinement $\vc_n$ of $\cu_n$ consists of co-zero sets which covers Y. There is a countable subcollection of $\vc_n$, viz. $\wc_n$ covers Y as  Y is Lindeloff. {f^{-1}(W):W∈ \wc_n} is a cover of X by co-zero sets. But this is not necessarily a ω-cover. Now how to apply condition (4) here to obtain (1)'

Comment: What does \bn denote? Also \vc, \cu, \wc, but I can guess those.